# Deploying android app to phone : error: [install_itemfolder_01] Error 1 Windows

Tags: android, qt

I’ve installed all components that I could possibly need, 
I’ve been on the net for two days and I just can’t find an answer to this question.
I’ve checked my apache ant, 
javac, 
java JRE, JDK, 
Qt Variables and everything is ok.

Qt likes all of my settings apart from when I try to deploy my app to emulator or device I get this error

Issues Output:

```
:-1: error: [install_itemfolder_01] Error 1
```

Compile Output :

```
17:54:43: Running steps for project Test...
17:54:43: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
17:54:43: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe"
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
17:54:45: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
17:54:45: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="C:\\Users\\ryan\\Desktop\\Projects\\Qt c++\\build-Test-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Release\\android-build" install
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
makefile:1716: recipe for target 'install_itemfolder_01' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_itemfolder_01] Error 1
17:54:45: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Test (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1))
When executing step 'Copy application data'
```

Is there anyone who can help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I Fixed it. 
For the love of life don't put any " " (Spaces) in your application path