# Qt 5.4 Windows Host Android Error while building/deploying project

Tags: android, qt, mingw32

I already have made a project with Qt and I wanted to build on Android.
It worked fine, but since I use another Workstation, I can't deploy my application.

I get the following log output :

`17:50:53: Could not start process "mingw32-make" INSTALL_ROOT="D:\Projects\Qt\Comp\build-proj-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_7_Qt_5_4_1-Release\android-build" install
Error while building/deploying project Proj (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.7, Qt 5.4.1))
When executing step "Copy application data"`

I checked my kits. All seems good.
My SDK and NDK works well, everything seems to work with Xamarin for example.

Regards,

Comment: Most probably [that's the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674406/deploying-android-app-to-phone-error-install-itemfolder-01-error-1-windows). It's a common problem with android builds.

Comment: I already try different folders name or anything. And as you can see, there is no space in the path. Still Strange.

Comment: Yup. Well, adding some info about sdk/ndk/ant(gradle?) and maybe a longer log would help. There are so many variables involved that the more information you give the more easier would be to find out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, solution was to add the mingw32-make to the PATH variable,
missed this originally as i had already added it as an override for the Make build step and thought that would be enough.